# linked nodes in while loop. (add two numbers from LeetCode)

Tags: python, singly-linked-list

Below is the answer to the addTwoNumbers linked node list question on LeetCode.

```
# Definition for singly-linked list.
# class ListNode:
#     def __init__(self, x):
#         self.val = x
#         self.next = None

class Solution(object):
    def addTwoNumbers(self, l1, l2):
    """
    :type l1: ListNode
    :type l2: ListNode
    :rtype: ListNode
    """
    result = ListNode(0)     
    temp = result

    carry = 0

    while l1 or l2 or carry:            
        val1  = (l1.val if l1 else 0)
        val2  = (l2.val if l2 else 0)
        carry, out = divmod(val1+val2 + carry, 10)    

        temp.next = ListNode(out)    
        temp = temp.next 

        l1 = (l1.next if l1 else None)
        l2 = (l2.next if l2 else None)

    return result.next
```

I am struggling to understand how

```
result = ListNode(0)     
temp = result
```

outside the while loop and

```
temp.next = ListNode(out)    
temp = temp.next
```

inside the while loop stores the linked nodes.

I feel that the code should leave `result.next` unchanged, as `result` is never called in the while loop, but it clearly isn't the case.

Comment: `result.next` points to the head of the new linked list you formed after adding, since you use temp to build up your result list

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh I guess I am struggling to understand how the linked list is built up such that result.next, result.next.next .... would give you subsequent numbers.

Comment: `temp.next = ListNode(out)     temp = temp.next`, essentially makes temp's next point to the new node, and then we move temp so that it points to the tail of the list where subsequent elements get added

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh  Just to make sure I understand this.. let's say the while loop is run only once.  Before the while loop is run, result.next would have been 'None.'  Also, temp.next would have been 'None.'  After one run of the while loop, temp.next is still 'None.'  But somehow, result.next is temp.val.  Could you explain to me why that is?

Comment: Because temp and result don't point to the same node. result points to the dummy node ListNode(0) while temp points to the last node in the newly formed list. Based on how long the new list is, result and temp might be closeby, example for a 2 element list, result and next may be next to each other, so `result.next` is `temp`

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh   I guess the trick is to notice that the first time 'temp.next = ListNode(out)' is run, it changes  both 'temp.next'  and 'result.next' from 'None' to 'ListNode(out)'    (Python changing both variables when the variables are set equal)